# Comparing a date to current server date using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to attempt to compare the current date with a date entry in a mySql database. It's code that I have found online and adapted as all the examples I have found hard-code the date to compare the current date with.
The trouble is even dates in the future are being marked as expired and I can't understand why this would be.
I am afraid that I am still new to PHP, so I may be making a schoolboy error!

```
$exp_date = KT_formatDate($row_issue_whatson1['dateToShow']);
$todays_date = date("d-m-Y");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);
if ($expiration_date > $today) { echo "Not expired"; } else { echo "expired"; }
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

I should add that the date time format used in the database entries is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What output does `KT_formatDate` give? I would look into http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php for your date conversions.

Comment: It outputs as dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a string then converting it to a timestamp, simply use mktime:

```
<?php
$today = mktime(
    0, // hour
    0, // minute
    0 // seconds
);
?>
```

The rest of the values will be filled according to today's date. If this still gives problems, put in some echo's for the values of `$exp_date` and `$expiration_date`.

#### Edit

Since this solved the problem, the discrepancy you were seeing was because you were doing the opposite with date('d-m-Y'). You were asking for the current date and the time values are then filled in with the current time. The expiration date in the database is likely set at midnight. With both dates being equal, and it being say 11am now, you are comparing `if (00:00:00 > 11:00:00)` which fails.

Comment: Thanks. I don't pretend to understand why but this sorted my problem out. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp_date = 14/05/2011 // todays date, int

$server_date = server.date() // servers date, int

// check exp_date against server date 
if ( $server > $exp_date)
    { echo "Sorry your 'service' has expired"; }
else 
    { echo "Welcome 'members_name' to StackOverflow"; }
```

Try that. However you need the right date format, as server.date() is probably different in PHP.

If problem still persists I would check whether your dates are strings or integers or both. That could possibly be the issue.

Hope that helps.

DL.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I tried this using date("d-m-Y") - which I understand is the correct usage in PHP, however I am seeing the exact message whether the db date is greater than or not!

Answer (score -2):

Your function does not seem to be valid.

```
function  KT_formatDate( $exp_date){

                 $exp_date = strtotime($exp_date);
                 $now = time();

                 if ($now > $exp_date)
                      return 'expired';
                 else 
                     return ' Not expired'; 
                }



$response = KT_formatDate($row_issue_whatson1['dateToShow']);
```

Comment: He's not making a function. KT_formatDate() is a function not defined in this snippet.

Comment: I'm sorry, you really have managed to lose me here :) - KT_formatDate($row_issue_whatson1['dateToShow']) is what is being used to display the database entry on the page, I wasn't aware that it was a function, so when I attempt to use it, I get an error message, changing the example above to NEW_formatDate didn't give me the result I needed.